# how to get intersect on redis's sorted sets?

Tags: redis, intersect, sortedset

I want to display leaders board for the users who are earning more points from two different games.

I am storing user scores as per games using redis's sorted sets, How I can get intersect on these games sorted sets to display common leaderborad.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

This sounds like a job for [`ZINTERSTORE`](https://redis.io/commands/zinterstore):

```
ZINTERSTORE leaders-sorted-set 2 game-1-sorted-set game-2-sorted-set AGGREGATE SUM
```

Since there is no `AVG` aggregate subcommand, you'll have to divide the resultant scores to obtain that.

Comment: Thanks for your response, can I get intersect without storing it in new key?

Comment: No, that's not supported.